# assembler pointer address - how does it gets it

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, memory-address

I have a big missunderstanding regarding pointers at the assembler level. I know that to get an address of a pointer (variable) u use

```
MOV EAX, variable
or 
LEA EAX, variable
```

and i also know that are many different OP codes for MOV but the one i amm interested is `MOV register, address`.

The question is ... how does it know at what address is the variable located ? Does the assembler make already `MOV EAX, address_of_variable` in the executable or the instruction is `MOV EAX, ...` and it finds that value and then get it's address. But how does it know how to search memory for that value and then return the address (supposing address change every time or so).

If this is a stupid question please forgive me , but i can't understand how does it do it.

Comment: `MOV EAX, variable` in NASM syntax assembles to the `mov eax, imm32` opcode.  The assembler leaves 4 bytes of zeros as the data, and the linker fills it in with the absolute address for that symbol reference (which is only known at link time).  There's never any "searching memory".  In MASM syntax, `mov eax, variable` is a load from that variable (but again, the absolute address is filled in by the linker, as the disp32 of the addressing mode instead of the imm32).  in NASM syntax, `lea eax, variable` is a syntax error; maybe you were thinking of `lea eax, [variable]`?

Comment: so the linker runs when i run the program ? when i execute the program , the linker is ran before my code ?

Comment: The linker is what creates an executable from assembler output.  .asm -> .o is the assembler.  `.o` -> `a.out` (or `.exe`) is the linker.

Comment: how can it be known at the link time ? does the linker put explicit memory addreses to executable ? and in case of .so or .dll where the address changes everytime  ? i know it uses virtual addresses and all are same for every program but still i dont understand .. :(

Comment: It's known at link time because executables aren't position-independent.  (They're loaded at a fixed address, and `mov eax, imm32` for addresses takes advantage of this).   You can't use `mov eax, var` in shared libraries, or other places where PIC (position indpendent code) is needed.  I'm going to write up these comments as an answer.  What OS should I use for examples?  And which assembler: NASM-style or MASM-style?  32-bit or 64-bit (where RIP-relative LEA solves the PIC problems)?

Comment: @123onetwothree I don't know which kind of variables you speak of but when you use variables with automatic storage durations (e.g. local variables in C++), these are usually put on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation), and address of these variables are retrieved relatively to two stack pointers (BP (stack Base Pointer) and SP (Stack Pointer) which are "updated" automatically when a function is called.

Comment: i dont refer to the stack (function) variables. global ones

Comment: @123onetwothree Then my answer is probably overkill for what you want ;) But the **Data Segment/BSS** part should be what you are looking for.

Comment: I just have to add, this is assembly language we're talking about. Truly no such thing as stupid questions - we should all win the Nobel's for doing this, while the majority thinks a JS-app bundled with 200mb of Chrome-libraries is something to be proud of. ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On standard architectures, the are various places where you can store variables:

- **Data Segment/BSS:** For global variables and static local variables (variables with static storage duration);
- **Stack:** Local variables (variables with automatic storage duration);
- **Heap:** Dynamic variables (variables with dynamic storage duration, allocated using `new` or `malloc`-like functions).

How the compiler resolves the address of a variable depends on where the variables is stored.

#### Data Segment/BSS

These are variables with static storage duration, the compiler know everything about them at compile times, and their address is known at link time. Take the following snippet:

```
int a = 0;

int main () {
    return a;   
}
```

Assembly (reduced):

```
a:
        .zero   4
main:
        ...
        movl    a(%rip), %eax
        ...
```

You have the data segments where `a` is located (top of the assembly), and to obtain the address of `a`, the compiler uses `a(%rip)` (x86 assembly specified). This will be "replaced" by the linker at link time - There is no "dynamic" computation of the address.

**Note:** No "dynamic" computation means that there are no instructions used to compute the address at run-time, but these addresses "live" in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (relative to the program itself), and will be translated to physical address at run-time by the [memory management unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit).

#### Heap

This is probably the most straightforward types of storage: The address of the variable is already stored somewhere, so you just retrieve it. Take the following snippet:

```
int main () {
    int *p = new int();
    return *p;      
}
```

Assembly:

```
main:
        ...
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax # Load p into rax (see the stack section)
        movl    (%rax), %eax   # Load *p into eax
        ...
```

See the stack section for the explanation on the first assembly instruction, but basically it stores the value of `p` into the `rax` register, and then it uses `(%rax)` to retrieve the value stored at the address in `rax` (if `rax` contains `0x8000`, then `(%rax)` is the value at the address `0x8000`).

#### Stack

Variables with automatic storage duration are stored on the stack, and their address are retrieved relatively to the stack pointer (which is a register that always points to the "base" of the stack). Take the following snippet:

```
int f() {
    int a = 4;
    return a + 2;
}
```

Assembly (reduced):

```
f():
        ...
        movl    $4, -4(%rbp)     # Set a = 4
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax   # Load a into eax
        addl    $2, %eax         # Add 2 to eax
        ...
```

In the above assembly, `rbp` is the *base pointer*, and as you can see, the address of `a` is retrieved relatively to it by `-4(%rbp)` (the first instruction is basically `a = 4`).

**Note:** The return value is stored in the `eax` register, and if there were, arguments to the function would be also put on the stack, but this behavior depends on the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), and other architectures may use different approaches.

Comment: In your heap example, the named variable `int *p` is a local with automatic storage (i.e. the stack).  I guess this does drive home the point that dynamic storage is different from static storage, in that the location is only known at run-time, and can be a value but not the address of a variable.

Comment: The comment is badly worded in `movl    -4(%rbp), %eax   # Store a into eax`.  That's a load, not a store, so you should say `load a into eax`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I updated the answer with `Load`. Regarding the heap part, I was mainly talking about `*p` (because, yes, `p` has automatic storage duration), I have added a small comment.